# Find the numbers coprime to their decimal digits

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory, primes

Two numbers are coprime if their greatest common divisor is 1.

Given a positive integer **N**, your task is to compute the first **N** terms of [OEIS A061116](http://oeis.org/A061116), which is the sequence of positive integers higher than 1 that are coprime to all their *decimal* digits.

Here are the first few terms of the sequence:

```
11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 51, 53, 57, 59, 61, 67, 71
```

You can assume that **N < 200**.

---

## Test Cases

```
Input -> Output

1 -> 11
3 -> 11, 13, 17
6 -> 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23
25 -> 11, 13, 17, 19, 21, 23, 27, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 49, 51, 53, 57, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 81, 83
```

You may output in any decent form (as a list, with a separator or whatever else). You can take input as the String representation of **N** or as an integer. [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) apply.

---

[Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Aw. can't this be a 'check if it's part of the sequence' :P

Comment: Also, why exclude 1? :|

Comment: @Okx That would be kind of trivial.

Comment: I need to finish my builtins so I can actually compete in these

Comment: @MartinEnder Because it is not in the OEIS sequence... Do you think I should include it?

Comment: Sorry If I will respond questions very late, but I will probably be offline for quite a long time

Answer (score 7):

## [Plain English](https://github.com/Folds/english) <s>853</s> <s>787</s> <s>738</s> <s>594</s> <s>550</s> <s>538</s> 532 bytes

Removed 66 bytes of white space.  Removed 49 bytes by using a more generic output type.  Removed 144 bytes by abbreviating variable names, and reusing the quotient and the remainder.  Removed 44 bytes by abbreviating an interface.  Shortened `Destroy the number things.` to `Destroy the L.`  Removed 6 bytes by changing "some" to "a", and "number" to "count".

Golfed code:

```
To create a L number things given a c count:
Put 0 in a i count.
Loop.
Add 1 to a n count.
If the i is at least the c, exit.
If the n is g,
append the n to the L;
add 1 to the i.
Repeat.
To decide if a n count is g:
If the n is at most 10, say no.
Put 1 in a m count.
Loop.
If the m is greater than the n, say yes.
Divide the n by the m giving a q quotient and a r remainder.
Divide the q by 10 giving the q and the r.
Get a gcd given the n and the r.
If the gcd is at least 2, say no.
Multiply the m by 10.
Repeat.
```

Ungolfed code:

```
Some special numbers are some number things.

To create some special numbers given a count:
  Put 0 in another count.
  Loop.
    Add 1 to a number.
    If the other count is at least the count, exit.
    If the number is coprime with its digits,
      Append the number to the special numbers;
      Add 1 to the other count.  
  Repeat.

To decide if a number is coprime with its digits:
  If the number is at most 10, say no.
  Put 1 in another number.
  Loop.
    If the other number is greater than the number, say yes.
    Divide the number by the other number giving a quotient and a remainder.
    Divide the quotient by 10 giving another quotient and another remainder.
    Get a gcd given the number and the other remainder.
    If the gcd is greater than 1, say no.
    Multiply the other number by 10.
  Repeat.
```

"Some number things" are a doubly-linked list of numbers.
The calling code has the responsibility to `Destroy the special numbers.`, so I have added the corresponding bytes.

The Plain English IDE is available at [github.com/Folds/english](https://github.com/Folds/english).  The IDE runs on Windows.  It compiles to 32-bit x86 code.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s>, 8 bytes

```
gQỊẠ
2Ç#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z898OHuroe7FnAZHW5X/v//vxkA)

2 bytes saved thanks to @Dennis!

Explanation:

```
        # Helper link: Is it in the sequence at all?
   Ạ    # All of...
g       # The GCDs of A and...
 Q      # The unique digits of A
  Ị     # Are less than or equal to 1
        #
        # Main link:
  #     # The first *n* truthy results of
 Ç      # The last link
2       # Starting at 2
```

Comment: Jelly is damn slick.

Comment: You can golf a byte off with the new(ish) updates: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98oPfDh7q6HuxYc26T8//9/MwA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 39 bytes

```
{(grep {$_ gcd.comb.all==1},2..*)[^$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiO9KLVAoVolXiE9OUUvOT83SS8xJ8fW1rBWx0hPT0szOk4lPrb2v7VCcWKlQpqGoYGBpvV/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>80</s> <s>70</s> 64 bytes

```
For[t=2;n=#,n>0,t++,Max[t~GCD~IntegerDigits@t]<2&&Print@t&&n--]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfLb8ousTWyDrPVlknz85Ap0RbW8c3sSK6pM7d2aXOM68kNT21yCUzPbOk2KEk1sZITS2gKDOvxKFETS1PVzdW7T@Yq@CQpuBgZPofAA)

*-10 bytes thanx to @MartinEnder*
*-6 bytes from  @JungHwan Min*

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <s>64</s> <s>59</s> <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 51 bytes

Saved a total of 6 bytes thanks to @Laikoni and @Ørjan Johansen

```hs
(`take`[x|x<-[2..],and[x`gcd`read[c]<2|c<-show x]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI6EkMTs1IbqipsJGN9pITy9WJzEvJboiIT05JaEoNTElOjnWxqgm2Ua3OCO/XKEiNlbzf25iZp6CrUJKPpcCEBQUZeaVKKgopCkYovGNTP8DAA)

Comment: 53 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI6EkMTs1IbqipsJGN9pITy9WJzEnR8PGSFMlPTlFoUKvKDUxRa@gtCjVRsWuOCO/XKEiVvN/bmJmnoKtQko@lwIQFBRl5pUoqCikKRii8Y1M/wMA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: 51 bytes with @Laikoni 's improvements + an inner list comprehension: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P81WI6EkMTs1IbqipsJGN9pITy9WJzEvJboiIT05JaEoNTElOjnWxqgm2Ua3OCO/XKEiNlbzf25iZp6CrUJKPpcCEBQUZeaVKKgopCkYovGNTP8DAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks, I don't often think of using \`...\`

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 115 bytes

```
q n=take n(filter(\x->1==(maximum$map(x%)(d x)))[11,13..])
d 0=[]
d x=mod(x)10:(d(x`quot`10))
x%0=x
x%y=y%(x`mod`y)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
↑tfȯεΠṠM⌋dN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR8A4P9odXNr///ihpF0ZsivzrXOoOG5oE3ijItkTv///zUx)

Comment: i. am. speed....

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 93 bytes

```
f=(n,k=11,g=(a,b)=>b?g(b,a%b):a)=>n?[...''+k].some(d=>g(k,d)>1)?f(n,k+1):[k,...f(n-1,k+1)]:[]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 120 bytes

```php
for($n=2;!$r[$argn-1];$t?:$r[]=$n,$n++)for($t=$i=0;~$s=("$n")[$i++];$t|=$d)for($d=$s?:$t|=1;$s%$d|$n%$d--;);print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcs/C8IwEAXwvd/CcEJDLFjBQc@jg3Rw0cWtlCL0X5ZruGYs/eox1uXgvfc7N7pwK9zokk5kkkY6N4m3PKRr2Txf78e91JjARwYmdb4oDP0kKTCdcAdSbUOW1wi@uMZcE/AB2Bi9MU9g6YgrzJQqYKUrsMb89ELQ/k1LMMff2OQI8x7aBTjeLEONTiz7JiLRGMIX)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èì ejX}jUB
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yOwgZWpYfWpVQg&input=MjU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 14 bytes

```
↑tfλΛȯεnḊ¹Ḋd)N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HbxJK0c7vPzT6x/tzWvIc7ug7tBBIpmn7///83AQA)

### Explanation

```
↑tfλΛȯεnḊ¹Ḋd)N
  fλ        )N filter all natural numbers by the following lambda:
    Λȯ     d   map each digit of the natural number, and check if all are truthy:
        Ḋ¹Ḋ    divisors of the digit and divisors of the argument
       n       set intersection
      ε        has length 1? (co primality check)
 t             remove the first element
↑              take n items from the sequence(n → input)
```